# in msword how to create a numbered list that each item has multiple paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

I'm working on a numbered list that each item may have multiple row breaks (ie. paragraphs) within it. like the below sample:

1) Nothing hurts a good soul and a kind heart more than to live amongst people who cannot understand it.

Ali-ibn-Abitaleb

2) Beautiful people are not always good,but good people are always beautiful.

Imam Ali (RA)

I tried to manually turn on and off the numbering feature but it takes time. is there a more simple walk-through?

Comment: Use <shift><enter> instead of <enter> after each of the numbered paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks a lot. It works. But write that as an answer so that I can vote it as right Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a more simple walk-through?

Instead of using <kbd>enter</kbd> (which starts a new numbered list item) use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> (which starts a new indented paragraph).